# How to handle empty response from DB?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, testing, automation

I am fetching value from db in dbval variable. So I want to add condition, pass the case if the value equals "*apple*" or the value is empty or null. But if the value is diff like "*orange*" or "*mango*", throw error.

My code:

```
if (StringUtils.equals(apple, dbval) || dbval.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || dbval.isEmpty()) 
{
    dbValueFlag = true;
    logger.info("DB value matched ",);
} 
else 
{
    logger.info("DB valuenot matched for pnac");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Apache Commons [`StringUtils.isEmpty(str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)), which checks for empty strings and handles `null` gracefully.

Example:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty("")); // true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isEmpty(null)); // true
```

**Or**

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()) { /* do your stuffs here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `throws InvalidArgumentException` to your method signature. And throw this exception from the else block in your code.

```
public void thisIsYourMethod(String dbVal) throws InvalidArgumentException {
    if (StringUtils.equals(apple, dbval) || dbval.equalsIgnoreCase(null) || dbval.isEmpty()) {
        dbValueFlag = true;
        logger.info("DB value matched ",);
    } else {
        logger.info("DB valuenot matched for pnac");
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Argument Passed in Wrong");
    }
}
```